# Ambiguous use of value in Enum

Tags: ios, swift

I have updated my swift project to Swift 4.1 and suddenly some of my code is showing error.

Could you suggest on what I have to do with these error ?

```
import Foundation

class HotCase : BaseResponse {

    enum HotCaseStatus : String {
        case New = "New"
        case InProgress = "In Progress"
        case Cancel = "Cancelled"
        case Complete = "Completed"
    }

    var Id: String?
    var STATUS: String?
    var CreateDate: String?
    var UpdateBy: String?
    var TYPE: String?
    var CASENUMBER: String?
    var REASON: String?
    var InternalId: String?
    var ORIGIN: String?
    var SUBJECT: String?
    var DESCRIPTION: String?
    var CLOSEDATE: String?
    var UpdateDate: String?
    var CreateBy: String?
    var ACCOUNTID: String?
    var isGotDetail: Bool = false


    var HotCaseStatus: HotCaseStatus? {
        get {
            if let state = STATUS {
                switch state {
                case HotCaseStatus.New.rawValue :
                    return .New

                case HotCaseStatus.InProgress.rawValue :
                    return .InProgress

                case HotCaseStatus.Cancel.rawValue :
                    return .Cancel

                case HotCaseStatus.Complete.rawValue :
                    return .Complete

                default: ()

                }
            }
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

I got the error showing Ambiguous use of 'HotCaseStatus' when I tried to use it in case.

Thank you.

Comment: Your naming is messy, I think thats the problem, try `var hotCaseStatus: HotCaseStatus?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you conformed to the naming convention that variable names start with a lowercase letter and struct and enum names start with e capital letter you easily would avoid such terminology confusion.

- The type is `HotCaseStatus`.
- The variable name is supposed to be `hotCaseStatus`

A type and an instance of a type cannot have the same name, that's the *ambiguity*.

Nevertheless the body of the computed property can be reduced to

```
var hotCaseStatus: HotCaseStatus? {
    return HotCaseStatus(rawValue: STATUS ?? "")   
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.

I have changed the variable name to hotCaseStatus

Could you suggest me on how I should use it in  switch and case if I use your code ?

Comment: You don't need a switch. Either the string (the raw value) can be converted to the enum then the enum case is returned otherwise `nil`.

Comment: Thank you I will try and let you know the result.

Comment: I have tried with your method and it seems to be working fine now.

Could you correct me whether I'm understand correctly or not ?
In this case, I can use your way instead of switch and case right.

Comment: Yes, my suggestion does exactly the same as the `switch` statement.

Answer (score 2):

```
var hotCaseStatus: HotCaseStatus? {
    get {
        if let state = STATUS {
            switch state {
            case HotCaseStatus.New.rawValue :
                return .New

            case HotCaseStatus.InProgress.rawValue :
                return .InProgress

            case HotCaseStatus.Cancel.rawValue :
                return .Cancel

            case HotCaseStatus.Complete.rawValue :
                return .Complete

            default: ()

            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

You are using property name same as enum name so, you getting issue.